# How to use sed to delete this string </p>\n</body>\n</html>"

Tags: sed, string

How to delete this string using sed?

```
</p>\n</body>\n</html>"
```

Comment: Do you have the string in a file or in a variable, or is it something read from another command?

Comment: Improve the question by adding the commands you have tried and the incorrect output to show your past effort. This is preferred rather than just requesting the community for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about ?

```
printf '%s\n' 'X</p>\n</body>\n</html>"'Y | sed -e 's,</p>\\n</body>\\n</html>",,'
XY
```

You need to escape the backslashes.  There is no need to escape the forward slashes if you use another delimiter with the substitution command (I've used commas above).

Comment: Thank you! My error was I though I only had to escape backwards slashes, this has solved my query.

Comment: @SamSep1ol You only have to escape the backslashes.